# Various Urllib2 errors when running Selenium webdriver on a VPS

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, vps, headless-browser

I'm using Selenium with Python bindings to scrape AJAX content from a web page with headless Firefox. It works perfectly when run on my local machine. When I run the exact same script on my VPS, errors get thrown on seemingly random (yet consistent) lines. My local and remote systems have the same exact OS/architecture, so I'm guessing the difference is VPS-related.

**For each of these tracebacks, the line is run 4 times before an error is thrown.**

I most often get this URLError when executing JavaScript to scroll an element into view.

```
File "google_scrape.py", line 18, in _get_data
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", e)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 396, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 355, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Occasionally I'll get this BadStatusLine when reading text from an element.

```
  File "google_scrape.py", line 19, in _get_data
    if e.text.strip():
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 55, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 233, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 355, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

A couple times I've gotten a socket error:

```
  File "google_scrape.py", line 19, in _get_data
    if e.text.strip():
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 55, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 233, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 355, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/home/ryne/.virtualenvs/DEV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I'm scraping from Google without a proxy, so my first thought was that my IP address is recognized as a VPS and put under a 5-time page-manipulation limitation or something. But my initial research indicates that these errors would not arise from being blocked.

Any insight into what these errors mean collectively, or on the necessary considerations when making HTTP requests from a VPS would be much appreciated.

#### Update

After a little thinking and looking into what a webdriver really is -- automated browser input -- I should have been confused about why `remote_connection.py` is making `urllib2` requests at all. It would seem that the `text` method of the `WebElement` class is an "extra" feature of the python bindings that isn't part of the Selenium core. That doesn't explain the above errors, but it may indicate that the `text` method shouldn't be used for scraping.

#### Update 2

I realized that, for my purposes, Selenium's only function is getting the ajax content to load. So after the page loads, I'm parsing the source with `lxml` rather than getting elements with Selenium, i.e.:

```
html = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
```

However, `page_source` is yet another method that results in a call to `urllib2`, and I consistently get the `BadStatusLine` error the second time I use it. Minimizing `urllib2` requests is definitely a step in the right direction.

#### Update 3

Eliminating `urllib2` requests by grabbing the source with javascript is better yet:

```
html = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.execute_script("return window.document.documentElement.outerHTML"))
```

#### Conclusion

These errors can be avoided by doing a `time.sleep(10)` between every few requests. The best explanation I've come up with is that Google's firewall recognizes my IP as a VPS and therefore puts it under a stricter set of blocking rules.

This was my initial thought, but I still find it hard to believe because my web searches return no indication that the above errors could be caused by a firewall.

If this is the case though, I would think the stricter rules could be circumvented with a proxy, though that proxy might have to be a local system or tor to avoid the same restrictions.

Comment: If you are scraping Google for search results, a headless browser (imo) is way too complicated an approach. Consider a non-JavaScript scraper such as Scrapy; Google will work fine without the client-side script. Better yet, can you use the Google search API?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I'm actually not scraping search results which is why I was hesitant to mention that Google was the domain. I'm scraping ajax content, so I need something to load javascript. That said, once the content is loaded there's no reason to continue using Selenium, so I'm currently reworking my script to call the webdriver's `page_source` method as soon as the page is loaded, close the driver, and then parse the source with `lxml`.

Comment: _I'm scraping ajax content, so I need something to load JavaScript._ - Can you connect directly to the URL for this? If so, you may not need to run JavaScript unless the response actually contains JavaScript. If it just contains JSON/HTML/XML, and the generation of the URL does not require JavaScript, then you can get away with Scrapy.

Comment: I did try that, but was unable to get a valid JSON (the keys were not strings). I tried fighting it with some regex's, but ultimately I figured that the URL would automatically change and that a headless browser solution would be more maintainable since I'm going to be running this scrape regularly. Perhaps that's a poor assumption?

Comment: It's quite possible, though it _may_ be the case that a trivially fixed Scrapy system is easier to maintain than a headless browser system anyway - much more to go wrong in the latter. I'd say though that Google blocking your server IP is a greater risk than their redesigning the page - they are not keen on scrapers, I believe.

Comment: With the information you've presented, I would still try a non-JavaScript solution first. You can always ask a parallel question about how to decode the response. What type were the keys, if they were not strings?

Comment: Good point. My understanding is that they don't mind <100 scrapes per day though, and my current needs fall below that threshold.

Comment: The keys were not quote-enclosed.

Comment: OK, well certainly it's worth putting a delay of a few seconds between each request, just in case.

Comment: Yep @halfer, pausing between requests ended up being the solution to my whole problem, though first minimizing the requests was very helpful. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per our conversation, you discovered that even for a small number of daily scrapes, Google has anti-scraping blocking in place. The solution is to put a delay of a few seconds between each fetch.

In the general case, since you are technically transferring non-recoverable costs to a third party, it is always good practice to try to reduce the extra resource load you are placing upon the remote server. Without pauses between HTTP fetches, a fast server and connection can cause a remote denial of service, especially to scrape targets that do not have Google's server resources.